# Load Woocommerce and Wordpress Functions Outside

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this structure on my website:

[image]

And inside the game folder (the `index.php` file)  I'm trying to call WooCommerce and WordPress functions, to see if the user has a membership *(I'm using WooCommerce Membership plugin)*.

With this code:

```
require_once('../wp-load.php' );

if (wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted($id) && !wc_memberships_is_user_member() && !current_user_can('administrator')) {
     header("Location: https:/localhost/mywebsite");
}
```

`wc_memberships_is_post_content_restricted();` is a WooCommerce Membership function... on the localserver *(wampserver)* it's working, but when I try to run on my online host the functions do not work.

I also used `var_dump( get_defined_functions() );` to see if the functions are properly load, and it's...

Comment: "...and it's..." what?  The SkyVerge team are really good about providing support so you should reach out to them to ask about functions that exist within their plugin.  Third-Party plugins and WooCommerce are off-topic on WPSE.

Answer (score 0):

When I am using a php script in my Wordpress installation, I have special functions in the child theme, in functions.php  So I have to require that as well.

Also you want to make sure that SHORTINIT is not defined as TRUE, or else you lose many Wordpress functions.

Here is how I do it.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require( $path.'/wp-load.php' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/../Divi-child/functions.php' );
// now all my functions are loaded
```